# C user name in linux - get current user name

Tags: c, linux

I would like to import files from the following path  :

import "/projects/tfs/users/**John**/verification/......

Is there is a way to change "John" to $USER in C so it will take the current user 
and not taking John's file always, I tried $USER and I get compilation error.

Is there is a way to do it in c ?

Comment: try `sprintf(str,"/projects/tfs/users/%s/verification",getenv("USER"))`.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: @usr-- that question seems to be more restricted than this one, e.g., it specifies not to use `getenv()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getpwuid](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) and [getuid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/geteuid) functions do to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    char path[PATH_MAX] = {0};
    struct passwd *p = getpwuid(getuid());

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/projects/tfs/users/%s/verification/.", p->pw_name);
        printf("%s\n", path);
    }

    return 0;
}
```